# Rspec Controller Testing - Errror: Expected [#<Contact id: 412...] Got [#<Contact id: 413]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I am using Ruby on Rails, RSPEC, and Factory Girl to write a test for my post action in my contact controller: here is my test:

```
describe "POST CREATE" do 
    it "assigns @contact and redirects" do 
      contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact, user_id: @user.id)
      post :create, contact: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:contact)
      expect(assigns(:contact)).to eq([contact])
      expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
```

Here is the controller I am testing:

```
 def create
    # render text: params
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.user=current_user
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Contact Created"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Couldnt Create"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Here is the user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do 
    email   { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { "32423fdsfasf42" }

    factory :user_with_contacts do 
      transient do 
        contacts_count 2
      end
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:contact, evaluator.contacts_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And lastly, here is the error I am getting:

```
   expected: [#<Contact id: 412, first_name: "Alia", email: "janet@weimann.name", phone_number: "6044339393", created_at: "2015-09-12 20:02:12", updated_at: "2015-09-12 20:02:12", last_name: "Schultz", user_id: 2703>]
        got: #<Contact id: 413, first_name: "Reggie", email: "kaley.kohler@ratke.org", phone_number: "6044339393", created_at: "2015-09-12 20:02:12", updated_at: "2015-09-12 20:02:12", last_name: "Zulauf", user_id: 2703>

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,10 +1,10 @@
   -[#<Contact:0x007ff74723ece0
   -  id: 412,
   -  first_name: "Alia",
   -  email: "janet@weimann.name",
   -  phone_number: "6044339393",
   -  created_at: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 20:02:12 UTC +00:00,
   -  updated_at: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 20:02:12 UTC +00:00,
   -  last_name: "Schultz",
   -  user_id: 2703>]
   +#<Contact:0x007ff744e02340
   + id: 413,
   + first_name: "Reggie",
   + email: "kaley.kohler@ratke.org",
   + phone_number: "6044339393",
   + created_at: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 20:02:12 UTC +00:00,
   + updated_at: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 20:02:12 UTC +00:00,
   + last_name: "Zulauf",
   + user_id: 2703>
```

It appears that two contacts are being created, one after the other - why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you create two different contacts. `contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact, user_id: @user.id)` and `post :create, contact: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:contact)` creates two contacts.

You should write something like this

```
post :create, contact: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:contact)
contact = Contact.last
expect(assigns(:contact)).to eq(contact)
expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
```

Comment: Doing this results in : >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>       

expected: [#<Contact id: 425, first_name: "Darby", email: "santa@windler.org", phone_number: "6044339393", created_at: "2015-09-12 21:22:43", updated_at: "2015-09-12 21:22:43", last_name: "Fadel", user_id: 2755>] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            got: #<Contact id: 425, first_name: "Darby", email: "santa@windler.org", phone_number: "6044339393", created_at: "2015-09-12 21:22:43", updated_at: "2015-09-12 21:22:43", last_name: "Fadel", user_id: 2755>

Comment: @SUPERUSER sorry it should be `eq(contact)` instead of `eq([contact])`